# What to do about tag [oneget]?

Tags: discussion, tags

There was recently a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/957712/how-do-i-use-windows-10-built-in-package-manager) regarding the Windows 10 package manager built-in to PowerShell. It was called **OneGet** during the preview and so there is a [[oneget]](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/oneget) tag that exists.

The official name was changed to **PackageManagement**. Is there anything that needs to be done regarding the tag?

Comment: Anything else? What was the first thing done to the tag?

Comment: Is there any standard for handling tags for products that are renamed?

Comment: At least a couple of the questions predate the name change.  I'm wondering if we should create a new tag and synonomize [oneget] with it.  If going forward, nobody will be trying to use the name oneget, that probably isn't necessary.  In terms of a new tag, there is already a [package-management] tag, so we're headed for confusion and tag misuse.  A new tag should be named something like [windows10-packagemanagement].  For whatever good it will do, both tags need a wiki summary that clarifies proper tag selection.

Comment: I was thinking a new tag would just be too confusing as well, there is already the one with a similar name that you mentioned. I wonder why they didn't stick with the name, it sounds better to me.

Answer (score 9):

There is already a tag in use under [package-management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/package-management) in a general sense.

OneGet's [new official spelling](http://blogs.technet.com/b/packagemanagement/archive/2015/05/05/10-things-about-oneget-that-are-completely-different-than-you-think.aspx) reads the same as the existing tag, but without a hyphen, and that would be a mess for mistagging.

The only option here then is to:

1. Create a [windows-packagemanagement](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-packagemanagement) tag (not restricted to version, plus it's 25 characters)
2. Synonymise [oneget](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/oneget) to the above